# Fetch the user information on mail id

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fetch "Registered user information" on my mail id through the "**mail()**" function.the mail() function worked fine and is able to send the mail on the mail id, but it can't fetch the user details. 
Here is my HTML code:

```
   <form action="registration.php" id="reg_form">
     <div class="form-msg alert with-icon alert-warning">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
        <span id="text-login-msg">
            Put your valid Emai id and we will mail you the login details on your register id.
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label>
            Name<span class="red">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <label>
            Email<span class="red">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>                                
      <div class="clearfix"></div>                              
      <div class="button-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg main-bg btn-block" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is my PhP Code:

```
$headers = "From: XYZ@gmail.com";
$to = "XYZ@gmail.com"; 
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = "Registration";
$email_message = "Form details below. \r\n";
$email_message .= "Name: ".$Name. "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".$Email. "\r\n";

mail ($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
header("Location: thank-you.html");
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `method="POST"` to your `form`, like:

```
<form action="registration.php" id="reg_form" method="POST">
```

The default value is "GET". In this case, you can read those inputs as `$_GET['name']` and `$_GET['email']`.

See this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: Thanks, It's Worked, the silly mistake was done by my side.

Answer (score 0):

`method` is missing in your form. You need to add that. Method defines whether you are sending values as GET or POST.

```
<form action="registration.php" id="reg_form" method='post'>
```

Comment: Thanks @Milan Chheda

Answer (score 0):

add in your first line `method="post"` :

```
<form action="registration.php" id="reg_form" method="post">
```